# PHP - MYSQL Images don't move (There is no error or negative get message)

Tags: php, file-upload

Problem is my images don't move to the uploads folder.. There is no syntax error or get message.. but all data saving to database.. So Why do not the images just move.. ? 
Here is mysql codes;

```
if(isset($_POST['addslider'])) {

$uploads_dir="../uploads";

@$tmp_name=$_FİLES['sliderimages']['tmp_name'];
@$name=$_Files['sliderimages']['name'];


$sliderrandom1= rand(10000,20000);
$sliderrandom1= rand(20000,30000);
$sliderrandom1= rand(30000,40000);
$sliderrandom1= rand(40000,50000);

$sliderrandomname="$sliderrandom1"."$sliderrandom1"."$sliderrandom1"."$sliderrandom1";

$refimgpath=substr($uploads_dir,3)."/".$name.$sliderrandomname;

@move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name$sliderrandomname");

$add_slider=mysql_query("insert into slider (slider_name, slider_imgpath, slider_order, slider_url ) VALUES ('".$_POST['slider_name']."','".$refimgpath."','".$_POST['slider_order']."','".$_POST['slider_url']."' ) ");


    if (mysql_affected_rows()) 
{

header("Location:../slider.php?addslider=ok");


}
        else 
        {

header("Location:../slider.php?addslider=failed");
        } }
```

I tried remove '@' but still there is no error.

Comment: The "@" in front of move_uploaded_file suppresses the error messages, so you don't see them. Does the upload folder have the correct permissions?

Comment: ohh I didin't know that, I just practicing what I watch on video.. I checked the folder and everything else, everything seems right.

Comment: Try to remove the @ and see if an error appears. Check the chmod of the upload folder. The folder should be writeable by the web server.

Comment: still same.. no error, no move

Comment: @$name=$_Files['sliderimages']['name'] should be $name=$_FILES['sliderimages']['name']

Comment: I removed all of them